# problems running qooxdoo simulation-run job

Tags: qooxdoo

I am trying to use the qooxdoo simulation-run job for this simple test (with changed class namespace of course):

```
qx.Class.define("twitter.simulation.Settings", {

   extend : simulator.unit.TestCase,

   members :
   {
       testChangeLanguage : function()
           {
                this.fail("Test not implemented!");
           }
   }
});
```

However, every time I try to run it, I get this very misterious error:

js: uncaught JavaScript runtime exception: TypeError: org.mozilla.javascript.Undefined@275b35 is not a function, it is org.mozilla.javascript.Undefined.

I am using Rhino 1.7R4 for the Javascript engine. The Selenium version is 2.25 and qooxdoo is at 2.0.2. Here is the simulation-run job config:

```
"simulation-run" :
{
  "let" :
  {
    "SIMULATOR_CLASSPATH" : 
    [
      "../selenium/selenium-java-2.25.0.jar",
      "../selenium/libs/*",
      "../rhino/js.jar"
    ]
  },

  "environment" :
  {
    "simulator.selServer"   : "localhost",
    "simulator.selPort"     : 4444,
    "simulator.testBrowser" : "*firefox",
    "simulator.autHost"     : "http://localhost:8080",
    "simulator.autPath"     : "/application/index.html"
  }
}
```

Comment: Which versions of qooxdoo and Selenium are you using, and what does your simulation-run job config look like?

Comment: I've edited the original question.

Comment: Rhino 1.7R4 is not supported from qooxdoo, instead use 1.7R3

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the 1.x Selenium client drivers.